# How do I find my React Expo app's web address?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I installed create-react-native-app, (downloaded Deco IDE, unrelated, but still using it), and created my first Hello World in React Expo in 5 minutes. Very impressed!

My first goal is to just create an app that sits on the web as I develop it. The web is easier to write than native apps, easier to get feedback, and way easier to configure.

Does my Expo app come with a public url from the moment I install and run create-react-native-app, or is there more work to do?

Also, I seem to be blocked from signing in. There's no reset password through the app. Is there on the web? If so, where.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: React native? I'm not sure what you mean by a "public URL". It's a device app.

Comment: I seem to recall that the folks at Expo had created a way to share your mobile app through the Expo server, delivered over the web. I thought they created that, but I haven't found that info yet. Was hoping to hear from someone at Expo.